# Why is my implementation of gradient descent on python producing outputs so slow?

Tags: python, gradient-descent

Why are the outputs from the code getting slow with every successive iteration?

I want to write a working code , that implements Gradient descent and Newton's method on same function and I want to compare the speeds and iterations for both the methods to arrive at the approximate solution.

This code snippet is only for Gradient descent , and the output seems to get slower for every iteration. So I got first 10 output relatively fast after that every output is taking atleast 5-6 seconds or more .

```py
#A python program to approximate a root of a polynomial
#using the newton-raphson method
import math
#f(x) - the function of the polynomial
h = 0.000001

def f(x):
    function = (x*x*x) - (2*x) - 1
    return function

def derivative(h,x): #function to find the derivative of the polynomial
    derivative = (f(x + h) - f(x)) / h
    return derivative

def GD(h,x):
    return (x - h*derivative(h,x))

# p - the initial point i.e. a value closer to the root

# n - number of iterations 

def iterate(p, n): #
    x = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if i == 0: #calculate first approximation
            x = GD(h,p)
        else:
            x = GD(h,iterate(x, n)) #iterate the first and subsequent approximations
        n=n-1
    return x

for i in range(100):
    print (iterate(1, i)) #print the root of the polynomial x^3 - 2x - 1 using 3 iterations and taking initial point as 1
```

I can't figure out whether it is happening due to code or the gradient descent.

Comment: How about using a tried and tested library like Scikit learn for this? Link to gradient descent documentation - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html

Comment: It looks like you are calling `iterate()` recursively with the same `n` before you decrement `n`. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: The last line which include the for loop for i, should not be there I don't why I put there , now I realise why the code was getting slow. Remove the last line of code and print every nth iteration in iterate() will produce wanted result

Comment: Can you justify your GD procedure? Usually, you perform a line search with the gradient. Here you just iterate `x -> x-f(x+h)+f(x)` which is only contractive if `h*f''(x)` is approximately `1`.